# Do all objects in a system need to have the same acceleration?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, linear-systems

What is the definition of a system? Could multiple objects accelerating at different magnitudes and directions still be considered a system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could multiple objects accelerating at different magnitudes and directions still be considered a system ?

Yes, definitely. A system is whatever set of objects you want to group together. Whether or not this is a useful way to group objects depends on the problem you are trying to solve.